# Combinatorial identity involving number of cycles (of any length) in a permutation

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am going through Phil Hanlon's [paper](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/30109/0000481.pdf?sequence=1) and on page 127, right after the first paragraph, "It is well known that.."
which boils down to the following identity:

$$
\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(\beta-i) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\beta^{c(\sigma)}
$$

where $c(\sigma)$ is the number of cycles (of any length) in a permutation.

I suspect this is not a difficult thing to prove, but I have not been able to find any literature that deals directly with this identity. Any help?

From the context, I think 
$
\beta
$
is positive and strictly less than 1.

Comment: Are you missing a sign somewhere? If $\beta=1$ then the LHS is zero but the RHS is $n!$.
EDIT: for a fixed $n$, both sides are polynomials in $\beta$, so if they are equal for $0<\beta<1$ then they are equal for $\beta=1$ too.

Comment: I edited the question, I'm pretty sure that from the context, beta is positive strictly less than 1.

Comment: Looking at the paper, I think it's $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (1-i\alpha) = \prod_{\sigma \in S_n} \alpha^{n-c(\sigma)}$.

Comment: Yes. I rewrote it. I used
$
\beta = \alpha^{-1}
$
Then it's the same equality, isn't it?

Comment: I wonder if Hanlon is missing a $\text{sgn}(\sigma)$ term in the summation.  Working out the $S_3$ example he has running through the article gives $2\alpha^2 - 3 \alpha + 1$ for the product but $2\alpha^2 + 3\alpha + 1$ for the sum (which is $\beta^3-3\beta^2+2\beta$ vs. $\beta^3 + 3\beta^2 + 2\beta$ in your formulation).

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the correct formula is actually

$$
\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(\beta+i) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\beta^{c(\sigma)}
$$

And this has a quite nice proof over on math.SE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/92051/21689).

Comment: Thank you. I'm going through it by hand for n=1,2,3.. and it does seem that it should be + and not -

Comment: Thank you very much! This also clears up some later applications in the paper.
This is just the result in Stanley V1 p. 27 (Prop. 1.3.7)

Answer (score 3):

Since I can't see immediately how Hanlon uses the equation, I guess the question is which "typo" was made.  Linus's equation is correct, but I also think $$ \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (\beta - i) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \beta^{c(\sigma)} $$ is true (and probably follows easily from Stanley's third proof referenced on the math.SE problem).

Comment: I see that now. From the context, it's clear he means the usual:
$$
\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(\beta+i) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\beta^{c(\sigma)}
$$
as Linus noted.

Thanks everyone for the quick help!